# How to pass data from render method to multiple components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React so looking like how can I render the data of image, name and user name from render method of one component to other components.

```
 class Avatar extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
         <img src={''} />
      )
   }
 }

class Label extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Name: </h1>
    )
  }
}

class ScreenName extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h3>Username: </h3>
    )
  }
}

class Badge extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Avatar />
        <Label /> 
        <ScreenName />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And the render method is this. How to read this image username and name into other components and update the view. Tried using {this.props.name} and also {this.props.user.name} but I am getting name as undefined.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Badge user={{
    name: 'Tyler McGinnis',
    img: 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/2933430?v=3&s=460',
    username: 'tylermcginnis'
  }} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And the HTML is this

```
<div id='app'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass data via the component's props. It looks like this:

```
class Avatar extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
         <img src={this.props.img} />
      )
   }
 }

class Label extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
    )
  }
}

class ScreenName extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h3>{this.props.username}</h3>
    )
  }
}

class Badge extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Avatar img={this.props.user.img}/>
        <Label name={this.props.user.name} /> 
        <ScreenName username={this.props.user.username} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And after some refactoring, you end up with this:

```
const Avatar = ({img}) => (
     <img src={img} />
);


const Label = ({name}) => (
    <h1>{name}</h1>
);

const ScreenName = ({username}) => {
    <h3>{username}</h3>
);

const Badge = ({user}) => (
    <div>
        <Avatar img={user.img}/>
        <Label name={user.name} /> 
        <ScreenName username={user.username} />
    </div>
)
```

Note that here we made use of so called **functional stateless components**, which can make your code a lot shorter and often more elegant. See [here](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data via props
https://codesandbox.io/s/o4nz576jn5